# Affordable camera for a macro photography

Tags: canon, macro, digital, sony, electronics

Which cheap camera fits better for taking a macro photos of static objects: PCB boards, electronic chips, various small hardware? Basically, the camera will be fixed on a copy stand. I'm considering Sony CyberShot DSC-W800 vs Canon IXUS 185. These are very similar models, although Canon IXUS 185 seems to be a little newer. Which from them has a better sensor?

Comment: Are you looking only at compacts?  Do you know what reproduction ratio you need?  Or do you just need close focusing?

Comment: Only compacts, yes. Not sure about ratio, just close focusing. For example, PCB board 15x10 cm: I need take top view of whole board, and also may need close-up view of selected areas, say 1x1 cm or 2x2 cm.

Comment: Most compact cameras have a "macro" mode that would be good enough for the shot of the whole board, but not for the "close up view of selected areas".  You'd need to shoot through something like a close-up filter, magnifying glass, or dissection scope.

Comment: Canon IXUS 185 have 1 cm the Closest Focusing Distance In Macro mode: isn't that enough for taking a close up view of small areas without additional lupes or filters?

Comment: Even with the lens that close, it might still image an area larger than 2x2 cm.  Lighting with the lens that close would also be challenging.

Comment: Consider getting the simplest semi-pro DSLM - eg a Sony A6000 - and then experiment with lenses. These cameras can take about 80% of lenses ever made with simple adapters, for manual focus - and manual focus is what you will be using for macro anyway. Great secondhand macro lenses can be quite affordable (eg Minolta MD 50mm/f3.5, which I find fantastic for electronics. Just don't try to use it as a non-macro - IMHO it has all the flaws of a tessar with none of the charms at long range).

Comment: ok, but these are not artistic photographs for magazines or presentations. These are technical photographs for engineering tasks. For the purpose, the compact camera with macro mode is sufficient. For Canon Ixus 185: how is achieved focusing from a distance of 1cm: with the help of objective lenses or entirely programmatically?

Comment: I don't think that either of these is a good choice. The lens is more important than the sensor. I think that a used Canon SX30 or a macro attachment to your phone will do better.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to have a Sony or Canon, you could get a used Olympus TG-4. It has what they call a "Microscope" mode. I just checked, and mine will focus down to about .5cm x .9cm. You can also get an accessory that snaps onto the front of the camera that distributes the flash to come from around the lens instead of just the one point. It is literally just a piece of plastic that redirects the light from the built-in flash. You can also get accessory telephoto and wide angle lenses that just snap on the front. And the bonus is that the whole thing is completely waterproof. You can even change the adapter lenses while the camera is under water, because they just snap on the front.

The camera is 16MP, which should be fine for documenting flaws in printed circuit boards.